# Save multiple radio buttons state using an Intent instead of 'saveInstance'

Tags: java, android

To put it short, I am making a simple Symptom Checker which allows general users to answer yes/no questions. I'm very new to Android Studio (only been coding less than a week) and have tried to make the mobile application save the radio buttons states so if a user backtracks a page the checked radio buttons show up. I grouped each questions yes and no radio buttons into separate radio groups to allow one selection of yes or no under each question.

Unfortunately, the buttons remain unchecked even after going to the next question page. Is there anyway the code I've wrote can easily be put into an intent or shared preference?

Questions Activity XML code to show how radio buttons are grouped:

```
         <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="214dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="32dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="55dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="134dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="32dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="50dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="300dp" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Here is the 'Questions' java file linked to the Questions activity:

```
public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {

private RadioButton radioButton;
private RadioButton radioButton2;
private RadioButton radioButton3;
private RadioButton radioButton4;
private RadioButton radioButton5;
private RadioButton radioButton6;
private RadioButton radioButton7;
private RadioButton radioButton8;
private RadioButton radioButton9;
private RadioButton radioButton10;
private RadioButton radioButton11;
private RadioButton radioButton12;


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //Question 1

    radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton); //yes
    radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton20); //no

    //Question 2

    radioButton3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton4); //yes
    radioButton4 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2); //no

    //Question 3

    radioButton5 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton6); //yes
    radioButton6 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton5); //no

    //Question 4

    radioButton7 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton7); //yes
    radioButton8 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton8); //no

    //Question 5

    radioButton9 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton9); //yes
    radioButton10 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton10); //no

    //Question 6

    radioButton11 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton12); //yes
    radioButton12 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton11); //no


    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption1", radioButton.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption2", radioButton2.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption3", radioButton3.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption4", radioButton4.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption5", radioButton5.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption6", radioButton6.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption7", radioButton7.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption8", radioButton8.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption9", radioButton9.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption10", radioButton10.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption11", radioButton11.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption12", radioButton12.isChecked());
    }

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    radioButton.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption1"));
    radioButton2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption2"));
    radioButton3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption3"));
    radioButton4.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption4"));
    radioButton5.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption5"));
    radioButton6.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption6"));
    radioButton7.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption7"));
    radioButton8.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption8"));
    radioButton9.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption9"));
    radioButton10.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption10"));
    radioButton11.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption11"));
    radioButton12.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption12"));

    }
}
```

The end goal, with the solution, is to utilize all the checked radio button boxes, make a big 'if then' statement which will allow patient symptom diagnosis.

An insight on implementation would be really useful, thank you.

Here is the entire class @JakeB:

```
package com.example.mhtapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button2;

private RadioButton radioButton;
private RadioButton radioButton2;
private RadioButton radioButton3;
private RadioButton radioButton4;
private RadioButton radioButton5;
private RadioButton radioButton6;
private RadioButton radioButton7;
private RadioButton radioButton8;
private RadioButton radioButton9;
private RadioButton radioButton10;
private RadioButton radioButton11;
private RadioButton radioButton12;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openquestion2();
        }
    });

    //Question 1
    radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton); //yes
    radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton20); //no
    //Question 2
    radioButton3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton4); //yes
    radioButton4 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2); //no
    //Question 3
    radioButton5 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton6); //yes
    radioButton6 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton5); //no
    //Question 4
    radioButton7 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton7); //yes
    radioButton8 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton8); //no
    //Question 5
    radioButton9 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton9); //yes
    radioButton10 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton10); //no
    //Question 6
    radioButton11 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton12); //yes
    radioButton12 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton11); //no
    }

public void openquestion2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Question2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption1", radioButton.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption2", radioButton2.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption3", radioButton3.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption4", radioButton4.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption5", radioButton5.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption6", radioButton6.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption7", radioButton7.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption8", radioButton8.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption9", radioButton9.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption10", radioButton10.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption11", radioButton11.isChecked());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption12", radioButton12.isChecked());
    }

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    radioButton.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption1"));
    radioButton2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption2"));
    radioButton3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption3"));
    radioButton4.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption4"));
    radioButton5.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption5"));
    radioButton6.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption6"));
    radioButton7.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption7"));
    radioButton8.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption8"));
    radioButton9.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption9"));
    radioButton10.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption10"));
    radioButton11.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption11"));
    radioButton12.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption12"));

   }
}
```

Comment: What isnt working here? ```onSaveInstanceState``` is called when the activity is paused, and ```onRestoreInstanceState``` is called when resumed. SharedPrefs is the correct way to stop temporary data, not intents.

Comment: The radio buttons which are previously checked become empty after clicking a button which goes to another activity. How would I go about implementing the sharedpreference?

Comment: SavedInstaneState should also be enough in this scenario, Move all the ```findViewById``` to the onCreate method.

Comment: @Zeeshan I recommend you to try Room database (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), read this and try it. because you are using too many options, using sharedPrefs will be mess for your purpose

Comment: Moved that part of the code into the onCreate method and built the application. Still getting the same problem unfortunately. There must be some way I just don't know off.

Comment: @majuran A database is fairly heavy duty for something that doesnt need to persist app instances..

Comment: @Zeeshan Please post the entire class

Comment: Added it to the edited question

Comment: @majuran I will look into this, it seems a database is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate back to the previous activity it might be generating a new activity instead of reusing the old one, set the activity launch mode to "singleInstance" in the manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Questions"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```